# Using Countifs with dates in named ranges as criteria and criteria range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to count how many dates exist ia list of dates between two dates. I can get the countifs to work if I hard code the dates in the formula I get a correct result. `=COUNTIFS(myDates,">=3/1/2023",myDates,"<3/10/2023")`. Where "myDates" is a named range of dates in A2:A100.

However if I put 3/1/2023 in cell G2 and 3/10/2023 in cell H2 and this formula `=COUNTIFS(myDates,">="&G2,myDates,"<" &H2)`, the result is 0.

I also get a zero result if I make G2 and H2 named ranges "start" and "end" respectively. `=COUNTIFS(myDates,">="&start,myDates,"<" &end)`

BTW If do something similar using numbers instead of dates the countifs works fin with both cell references and named ranges.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Found all the three formulas seems to be working on my end, unless your `start` and `end` are formatted as text or have any white spaces/non breaking characters.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. A couple of things to check:

1. All cells are formatted General/Date and dates are entered as date values
2. Try using Evaluate Formula from the Formulas Ribbon and Evaluate step-by-step, checking that the COUNTIFS function is correct before the final calculation.

Select the cell containing the formula, then click Evaluate Formula
[image]

Note that it should display date serials instead of dates when constructing the conditions. It should go from:

[image]

to:

[image]

Comment: Yes all seems to be working.

Comment: Unfortunately I am working on a Mac so Excel is somewhat crippled. Macs don't seem to have the Evaluate Formula feature.

Comment: @PhilNBlanks Yes, its not there in Excel for Mac but you can do one thing --> highlight a portion of a formula in the formula bar and press `F9` to calculate that highlighted section of the formula. Remember to press `ESC` key otherwise the evaluated section of the formula will replace the original.

Comment: @PhilNBlanks have you tried adding double unary `--` before the start and end dates, could try once --> `=COUNTIFS(myDates,">="&--G2,myDates,"<" &--H2)` when its returning zero probably its reading as text